# what is the id="Result_box" tag used for?

Tags: html

What is the `Tag id="result_box"` used for? I am seeing this in the `blogger>Compose>HTML section`. Can someone explain the use of that tag?

Answer (score 0):

The id attribute specifies a unique id for an HTML element (the value must be unique within the HTML document). The id attribute is most used to point to a style in a style sheet, and by JavaScript (via the HTML DOM) to manipulate the element with the specific id.

Please refer [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id)

Here your html element have a unique id you named it as "result_box"